# dx-data-grid save button active

Tags: javascript, angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

dx-data-grid add event without inside add button like batch add operations.

I use these versions

angular 10.2

devextreme 20.2.5

devextreme-angular 20.2.5

I have a dx-data-grid as below

```
<dx-data-grid
    id="gridContainer"
    [dataSource]="myCustomDataStore"
    [showBorders]="true"
    [remoteOperations]="true"
    [repaintChangesOnly]="true"
    (onSaving)="onSaving($event)">

    <dxo-editing
        mode="batch"
        [allowAdding]="true"
        [allowDeleting]="true"
        [allowUpdating]="true"
    ></dxo-editing>
  <!--here is my columns -->
</dx-data-grid>
```

setNewLine() {
this.myCustomDataStore.store().push([
{ type: "update", data: data }
]);
}

i want to when I II click setNewLine() , create a new line as batch new line like this. Because otherwise save button wont activate.

How can i active save button.

i haven't seen like this image
[image]

Comment: Did you inspected devextreme demo examples?

Comment: @Archi.Moore yes i tried many   example and properties but i didn't find any soltion for my case

Comment: Problem is that you push data in data store, but you need call datagrid addRow event and then set data by initNewRow event handler.

Comment: @Archi.Moore acually i tried it it just give a new line i want to call these function without grid as a custom button